# Resizing added painted components and strange swing behaviors

Tags: java, swing

I have this problem bothering me for days. I'm making a special paint program. I made a JPanel, and added custom jComponents which are painted using the paint(..) method.
The problem is, whenever I resize the window, all the added components "disappear" (or just don't paint) so I end up with a empty frame.

Also i noticed some strange behaviors of swing when using this method. I have added comments to the code describing this problem.

```
package simple;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.*;

public class SimpleFrame extends JFrame {
    JPanel paintArea;
    SimpleCanvas c1;
    SimpleCanvas c2;
    ArrayList<SimpleCanvas> list;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleFrame frame = new SimpleFrame();

    }

    public SimpleFrame() {
        super("Test");
        setSize(600,500);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //The panel to which my SimpleCanvas objects are added
        paintArea = new JPanel();
        paintArea.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 500)); 
        paintArea.addMouseListener(new paintAreaMouseEvents());
        getContentPane().add(paintArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        setVisible(true);
        paintArea.setVisible(true);

        //A list to hold all the objects together
        list = new ArrayList<SimpleCanvas>(10);

        //The same as in class paintAreaMouseEvent, but doesnt work
        SimpleCanvas c = new SimpleCanvas();
        c.setBounds(60, 100, 100, 50);
        list.add(c);
        paintArea.add(list.get(list.size() - 1));
        paintArea.repaint();
    }
    //When you click the mouse, it makes an oval
    class paintAreaMouseEvents extends MouseAdapter {
        @Override
        //This does work.
        public void mouseClicked (MouseEvent me) {
            SimpleCanvas c = new SimpleCanvas();
            c.setBounds(me.getX() - 50, me.getY() - 25, 100, 50);

            list.add(c);
            paintArea.add(list.get(list.size() - 1));
            paintArea.repaint();
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the SimpleCanvas class

```
package simple;

import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.JComponent;

public class SimpleCanvas extends JComponent {
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.fillOval(0, 0, 100, 50);
    }
}
```

Thanks :)

BTW: Just wanted to say this site is amazing. I came here a lot while using Google, and now I finally decided to make an account.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is a layout problem. Add:

```
System.out.println(getSize());
```

to your JComponent's paint method to see what happens when you resize the GUI.

This is happening because the resize is invoking the layout manager actions.

To solve this, don't use `setBounds(...)` to size components but rather the layout managers. Also override your JComponent's getPreferredSize method if you want the layout managers to respect a specific size for it. Finally, don't paint with the `paint` method but rather the `paintComponent` method. The tutorials will explain why.

Also, if you absolutely need to position something using absolute positioning, then the container must use a null layout:

```
  // The panel to which my SimpleCanvas objects are added
  paintArea = new JPanel(null);
```

**Edit**
If I were doing something like your program above, I'm not sure that I'd add new components to a JPanel but rather would simply have the drawing JPanel hold a list of Shapes and then have the shapes drawn in its paintComponent method using a for loop.  For example:

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.Stroke;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.*;

public class SimpleFrame2 extends JPanel {
   private static final Color ELLIPSE_COLOR = Color.LIGHT_GRAY;
   private static final Color ELLIPSE_FILL_COLOR = Color.blue;
   private static final int PREF_W = 600;
   private static final int PREF_H = 500;
   public static final int ELLIPSE_WIDTH = 100;
   public static final int ELLIPSE_HEIGHT = 50;
   private static final Stroke ELLIPSE_STROKE = new BasicStroke(2f);
   private List<Shape> shapes = new ArrayList<Shape>();

   public SimpleFrame2() {
      addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
         @Override
         public void mousePressed(MouseEvent mEvt) {
            double x = mEvt.getX() - ELLIPSE_WIDTH / 2;
            double y = mEvt.getY() - ELLIPSE_HEIGHT / 2;
            double w = ELLIPSE_WIDTH;
            double h = ELLIPSE_HEIGHT;
            shapes.add(new Ellipse2D.Double(x, y, w, h));
            repaint();
         }
      });
   }

   @Override
   protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
      // to draw smooth edges
      g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
      g2.setStroke(ELLIPSE_STROKE);
      for (Shape shape : shapes) {
         g2.setColor(ELLIPSE_FILL_COLOR);
         g2.fill(shape);
         g2.setColor(ELLIPSE_COLOR);
         g2.draw(shape);
      }
   }

   @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("SimpleFrame2");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(new SimpleFrame2());
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

**Edit 2**
with dragging of shapes

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Stroke;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class SimpleFrame3 extends JPanel {
   private static final Color ELLIPSE_COLOR = Color.LIGHT_GRAY;
   private static final Color ELLIPSE_FILL_COLOR = Color.blue;
   private static final int PREF_W = 600;
   private static final int PREF_H = 500;
   public static final int ELLIPSE_WIDTH = 100;
   public static final int ELLIPSE_HEIGHT = 50;
   private static final Stroke ELLIPSE_STROKE = new BasicStroke(2f);
   private List<RectangularShape> rects = new ArrayList<RectangularShape>();

   public SimpleFrame3() {
      MyMouseAdapter myMouseAdapter = new MyMouseAdapter();
      addMouseListener(myMouseAdapter);
      addMouseMotionListener(myMouseAdapter);
   }

   @Override
   protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
      // to draw smooth edges
      g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
      g2.setStroke(ELLIPSE_STROKE);
      for (RectangularShape rect : rects) {
         g2.setColor(ELLIPSE_FILL_COLOR);
         g2.fill(rect);
         g2.setColor(ELLIPSE_COLOR);
         g2.draw(rect);
      }
   }

   @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
   }

   class MyMouseAdapter extends MouseAdapter {
      private RectangularShape selectedRect = null;
      private Point deltaPt = null;

      @Override
      public void mousePressed(MouseEvent mEvt) {
         if (mEvt.getButton() != MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
            return;
         }

         if (rects.size() > 0) {
            for (int i = rects.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
               if (rects.get(i).contains(mEvt.getPoint())) {
                  selectedRect = rects.get(i);
                  rects.remove(selectedRect);
                  rects.add(rects.size(), selectedRect);
                  deltaPt = new Point(mEvt.getX() - selectedRect.getBounds().x,
                        mEvt.getY() - selectedRect.getBounds().y);
                  repaint();
                  return;
               }
            }
         }
         double x = mEvt.getX() - ELLIPSE_WIDTH / 2;
         double y = mEvt.getY() - ELLIPSE_HEIGHT / 2;
         double w = ELLIPSE_WIDTH;
         double h = ELLIPSE_HEIGHT;
         Ellipse2D ellipse = new Ellipse2D.Double(x, y, w, h);
         rects.add(ellipse);
         selectedRect = ellipse;
         deltaPt = new Point((int)(mEvt.getX() - x), (int)(mEvt.getY() - y));
         repaint();
      }

      @Override
      public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
         if (selectedRect != null) {
            Rectangle bounds = selectedRect.getBounds();
            bounds.setLocation(e.getX() - deltaPt.x, e.getY() - deltaPt.y);
            selectedRect.setFrame(bounds.x, bounds.y, bounds.width, bounds.height);
            repaint();
         }
      }

      @Override
      public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
         if (selectedRect != null) {
            repaint();
            selectedRect = null;
         }
      }
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("SimpleFrame3");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(new SimpleFrame3());
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I added the null parameter to jPanel's constructor, and all my problems were solved.
I guess I'll have to learn how to use LayoutManagers now ;)
Again, thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I will definitely keep it in mind. The problem is I'm writing a program which also enables you to move the shapes by adding another mouseEventHandler to the custom Canvas class, so the method you suggested wouldn't work.

Comment: @Charnia: dragging is easily implemented with adding more code to the MouseAdapter so that it responds to mouseDragged. For example see the code in Edit 2 above.

Comment: I tested your little program, and I noticed you managed to have the selected ellipse follow the mouse, something i didn't manage to do (It would jump from its origin to its destination).

One last question though: on line 85 you wrote:

`deltaPt = new Point((int)(mEvt.getX() - x), (int)(mEvt.getY() - y));`
but i'm wondering why you did that? Just a line you missed when copy pasting parts of the code?
Anyway, thanks for all your help. This was a wonderful first experience with StackOverflow and it's community ;)

Comment: And I have decided to throw everything away and start again using your way. My program has become too chaotic, and I think your method is much better.